# Getting the temp from a MCP9701 chip using the Intel Edison Arduino Board?

Tags: node.js, temperature, intel-edison

I am using a MCP9701 temperature chip.  The MCP9701 is connected to my Edison Arduino breakout board pin A0, 5v and ground.

The output temp is:

c: 25.4 f: 77.8

My room temp thermometer says 71.8 and the Edison is calculating my room temp as 77.8.  The temperature is definitely NOT 77.8 in my room.

I tried changing the `setBit(10)` to `setBit(12)` which resulted in a temp of 200.7. I also changed the setBit to 8 which results to a -8 temp.  How do I get the proper temperature calculation using NodeJS?

NodeJS code:

```
var m = require('mraa');
var a0 = new m.Aio(0);
a0.setBit(10);

console.log("reading analog input>>>");

function CompareForSort(a,b) {
  if (a == b)
    return 0;
  if (a < b)
    return -1;
  else
    return 1;
}

function MedianRead(n, tempType) {
  var myarr = [];

  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    var v_out;
    var temp;

    v_out = a0.read();
    v_out*=.0048;
    v_out*=1000;
    temp=0.0512 * v_out -20.5128;
    var tempinf = temp * (9 / 5) + 32;

    switch(tempType) {
      case 'c':
        myarr[i] = temp;
        break;
      case 'f':
        myarr[i] = tempinf;
        break;
      default:
        myarr[i] = temp;
    }
  }

  myarr.sort(CompareForSort);
  myarr.splice(n-2,2);
  myarr.splice(0,2);
  m=myarr.length;

  var sum=myarr.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return a+b;
  });

  var temp = sum/m;
  var tempFixed = temp.toFixed(1);

  console.log("Temp: " + temp + " Fixed Temp: " + tempFixed);
  console.log(tempFixed);
}

setInterval(function() {
  MedianRead(200, 'f');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: >±4°C Accuracy from 0°C to +70°C >-4°C/+6°C Accuracy from -10°C to +125°C +4c is within the range you're seeing, isn't it?